Create a TypeScript generic type that maps arbitrarily named types to other types
I've got some code that maps 'to -> from' types like this:
/**
 * From types:
 */
type Kitten = {
    kind: 'kitten';
};
type Puppy = {
    kind: 'puppy';
};

/**
 * To types:
 */
type Cat = {
    kind: 'cat';
};
type Dog = {
    kind: 'dog';
};

/**
 * Existing generic "condtional type" that converts any "FROM" -> "TO" using nested ternaries (slow when big):
 */
type ConvertType<T> = 
      T extends Kitten ? Cat 
    : T extends Puppy  ? Dog 
    : never;

However in reality, there's 100+ pair mappings, and therefore nested ternary conditions, which really slows TypeScript down.
Is there some better way to do this without using a slow "conditional type"?
I know it could also be done with a dummy function with overloads like this...
function convert_function(input: Kitten): Cat;
function convert_function(input: Puppy): Dog;
function convert_function(input: unknown) {
    return input;
}

...but I'm wondering if it can just be done purely with the typing system alone, as I am already with ConvertType<T>, but without the performance issues.

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks, looks like it achieves the functionality.  With 100+ mappings, do you think it will perform much better than the conditional type does?  And better/worse than function overloading would?

It is a single conditional type so it is indeed likely to perform significantly better, but I'm not really an expert on compiler performance so I can't say for sure, and the only way to really know is to test with representative cases anyway.  As for overloading it really depends on the use cases. If you arrange the overloads in order of how commonly they are called it might be faster to use overloads? Again though: no idea and it's something that only testing could answer.  Shall I write up the answer with Extract and not worry about trying to definitively answer performance stuff?

Another idea, if your worried about speed is maybe storing the linked type with the type.  TS then won't need to do any form of lookup.  One gotcha is if you mouse over it won't say Cat, but {kind: 'cat'}, but because of Duck typing in TS there actually equal, and may even help performance more.  If you make the type an optional and prefix with _, it would also help in indicating it's just for Type reasons.

eg...  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0glsYEB2UC8UDeAoKeoDWcyAJgFxQDkRiKlA3LvgPpgCGATisACrgQB+CgGE2wRgF9GoSFAAKAVzBgQ6LEzxFSFSmCUqGGqK07c+kIVAAiAewDmkxtgD0AKle5XUHjagyIAM5kns7Y-lCiwGo4+ITE5FQAxmKGUmH81vbRRloJlCT2qU7hPuYQADw8AHxqPFAQAB5IpAFQABSYJlzIvPyWxABmEBxQABoSAJRQAmNQFMgQAG7DxRmjtTZl5fC0yFX0UM7OWLk6ycCUUBLpsgCaG1uKyiD7eEcn8ToFdpTXLs4AORsSCgCEorUwpySKQkABo8AAjBRRBEQZIKALQGwDawKRIEbzgYh2UGtRI2DhcRLAWH-NikKAAWzYqiWKCgAAsIAAbMBMinQADuCA5UEgHAGFOZyES0GI3gAythsOTkAEog0yOsMJDPtCLmlVeqoCAyJE1A0Dv8jVEAF5kWwkjCWw7OYYcCnKoA

@Keith Thanks for the suggestion, however I don't want to modify all the existing 'from' types.

@jcalz
I did a quick hack in my project yesterday with some regex to use your tuple-based generic type on my 334 pairings.
Looks like it's working better now, thanks!
Yes feel free to submit as an answer if you'd like.  Will mark it as the answer.

You should be able to make a union representing the pairings you care about, like
type TypeMap = [Kitten, Cat] | [Puppy, Dog]

That uses tuples to pair things, but you could use any type you want, like {i: Kitten, o: Cat} | {i: Puppy, o: Dog}, as long as it's consistent.
And then a single distributive conditional type can filter it appropriately:
type ConvertType<T> = Extract<TypeMap, [T, any]>[1]

This uses the Extract utility type (implemented as a distributive conditional type) to filter TypeMap to just the entry whose first element is T, and then it indexes into that entry to get the second element (with index of 1).
Let's test it out:
type X = ConvertType<Kitten> 
//   ^? type X = Cat
type Y = ConvertType<Puppy>
//   ^? type Y = Dog

Looks good.
Playground link to code
